# What do I do to fix jqGrid throwing an error when (multi)selecting a row: 'className' is null or not an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I had selecting rows working fine. I then went and refactored my code to use OLN and added some defaults to my grid.

Here is the default block of code:

```
var Grid = {  
SiteMaster: {
    setDefaults: function () {
        $.jgrid.defaults = $.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
            datatype: 'json', 
            height: "100%",
            loadui: 'block',
            images: "/images/",
            jsonReader: {
                root: "Rows",
                page: "Page",
                total: "Total",
                records: "Records",
                repeatitems: false,
                userdata: "UserData",
                id: "Id"
            },
            loadui: "block",
            mtype: 'GET',
            autowidth: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20],
            viewrecords: true
        });
    }
  }
};
```

and here is the actual grid code:

```
setupGrid: function (grid, pager) {
            disableControls();
            grid.jqGrid({
                colNames: ['Description', 'Ship Date', 'Memo'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 400, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'ShipDateDisplay', index: 'ShipDateDisplay', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'Memo', index: 'Memo', width: 200, align: 'left'}],
                pager: pager,
                url: gridurl,
                pager: pager,
                multiselect: true,
                multiboxonly: true,
                loadComplete: enableControls
            });

            initGridSearch();
        }
```

Here are my script references, too:

```
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/jquery.ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/grid.addons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/grid.postext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/grid.setcolumns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/jquery.searchFilter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="/CommonWeb/js/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/Global.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/Grid.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Since the refactor, everytime I click on a row or select it via the check box controls, I get the javascript error **'className' is null or not an object.** Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't sending a unique identifier down with the data. This data was coming from a legacy table with no key on it. Once I slapped an identity field on it and generated an Id, everything started working again.

Comment: I have had the same problem, but i have had an id-field. The problem was that the data in this field was not unique (*yikes*)

Answer (score 0):

You posted not enough code to reproduce the problem. Which version of jqGrid you use?

The code of `setDefaults` where you try to set some defaults in `$.jgrid.defaults` seems incorrect for me. You should not assign the results of `$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {...})` to `$.jgrid.defaults`. The correct will be just call [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

What is `images: "/images/"` parameter? You don't need define `loadui: 'block'` twice (second time as `loadui: "block"`).

Inserting of `jquery.jqGrid.js` or inserting of `grid.locale-en.js` before it seems me wrong. I recommend you to look inside of `jquery.jqGrid.js`. Version 4.0 of jqGrid include `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` which is probably better to use.

Why you inserted so much modules? Do you use it? For example inserting of old `jquery.searchFilter.js` can overwrite new searching module `grid.filter.js` of jqGrid.

You should remove default value `align: 'left'` from the `colModel`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on the dup entries and extra modules. I didn't really think about the modules and just chucked them all in. This is jqGrid 4.0, so you're right on that. It errors if I move the locale file after the jqgrid file, just fyi. I did fix my problem though, see answer.

Comment: @IronicMuffin: If you move "the locale file after the jqgrid file" you receive another error because `grid.locale-en.js` in inserted as the part of `jquery.jqGrid.js`. The problem is that jqGrid **has no** `jquery.jqGrid.js` file. There are only the `grid.loader.js` in the `scr` directory. If the server response has non-unique ids it is an error, but you will **never** has any exception like you described. The exception exist in case of you not include some JavaScript file or **include one JavaScript file more as once**. I am sure that it was your error.

Comment: Oleg, I renamed jquery.jqGrid.src.js to jquery.jqGrid.js myself. I disagree with your analysis of the exception. I made sure to return unique ids and it worked immediately.